# unable to open phpmyadmin Error during session start; please check your PHP ....etc

Tags: firefox, apache-http-server, php, mysql

I have installed xampp on ubuntu. I can access on firefox localhost/xampp.
However when I go to phpmyadmin on the left it comes up with
"phpMyAdmin - Error"
Then underneath that it has this:
"Error during session start; please check your PHP and/or webserver log file and configure your PHP installation properly. Also ensure that cookies are enabled in your browser."

Comment: What do you find in your apache log ?

Answer (score 3):

First ensure your `session.save_path` in your **php.ini** is set correctly

then check directory permission

```
sudo chmod 777 /var/lib/php/session/
```

Finally, clear everything (cache, cookies ..) at browser end, refresh and check

If you make any change in **php.ini**, restart apache

Answer (score 0):

The problem can also be that you have a wrong `session.save_handler` value in your `php.ini`. I got this error when I changed it to `memcached`, and worked again when changing back to `files`